# How to limit the product attbribute in custome template of woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am able to get the attribute by selected custom attribute name like 'color','size','weight' and more in table row but i want to show only 3 rows.
my working code is bellow but its showing all of them i just want to show only 3 rows

```
add_action( 'cw_shop_page_attribute', 'cw_shop_page_attribute', 25 );

function cw_shop_page_attribute() {
global $product;
$display_size = $product->get_attribute('display-size');
$processor = $product->get_attribute('processor-type');
$rearcamera = $product->get_attribute('primary-camera');
$frontcamera = $product->get_attribute('secondary-camera');
$storage = $product->get_attribute('internal-storage-gb');
$m_ram = $product->get_attribute('ram-gb');
$frontcamera = $product->get_attribute('secondary-camera');

if ( $display_size ) {
    echo'<tr class="_plspcdt"><td class="_plspcicon"><i class="fa fa-desktop fa-2x"></i></td><td class="_atrbttl">Display</td>';
    echo'<td class="_atrbvlu">'; printf ($display_size);
    echo'</td></tr>';
   }
if ( $processor ) {
    echo'<tr class="_plspcdt"><td class="_plspcicon"><i class="fa fa-microchip fa-2x"></i></td><td class="_atrbttl">Processor</td>';
    echo'<td class="_atrbvlu">'; printf ($processor);
    echo'</td></tr>';
   }
if ( $rearcamera ) {
    echo'<tr class="_plspcdt"><td class="_plspcicon"><i class="fa fa-camera fa-2x"></i></td><td class="_atrbttl">Rear Camera</td>';
    echo'<td class="_atrbvlu">'; printf ($rearcamera);
    echo'</td></tr>';
   }  
if ( $frontcamera ) {
    echo'<tr class="_plspcdt"><td class="_plspcicon"><i class="fa fa-camera fa-2x"></i></td><td class="_atrbttl">Front Camera</td>';
    echo'<td class="_atrbvlu">'; printf ($frontcamera);
    echo'</td></tr>';
   }
```

how to show only 3 rows of them and hide if empty

Answer (score 0):

[get_attribute()](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/8bada412d4c9d4329655c801eb903ca2882fbdc5/plugins/woocommerce/includes/abstracts/abstract-wc-product.php#L1990) returns a comma separated string of the values, so you can use php's explode function to loop through the values as an array and then bail after 3 results have been returned.

For example:

```php
if ( $display_size ) {
    echo'<tr class="_plspcdt"><td class="_plspcicon"><i class="fa fa-desktop fa-2x"></i></td><td class="_atrbttl">Display</td>';
    $display_size_array = explode( ',', $display_size );
    $count = 0;
    foreach ( $display_size_array as $attribute ) {
        if ( $count >= 3 ) {
            break;
        }
        echo'<td class="_atrbvlu">' . $attribute . '</td';
        $count++;
    }
    echo'></tr>';
}
```

Comment: $display_size = $product->get_attribute('display-size');
$processor = $product->get_attribute('processor-type');
$rearcamera = $product->get_attribute('primary-camera');
$frontcamera = $product->get_attribute('secondary-camera');
$storage = $product->get_attribute('internal-storage-gb');
$m_ram = $product->get_attribute('ram-gb');
$frontcamera = $product->get_attribute('secondary-camera');

Comment: $display_size = $product->get_attribute('display-size');
    $processor = $product->get_attribute('processor-type');
    $rearcamera = $product->get_attribute('primary-camera');
    $frontcamera = $product->get_attribute('secondary-camera');
    $storage = $product->get_attribute('internal-storage-gb');
    $m_ram = $product->get_attribute('ram-gb');
    $frontcamera = $product->get_attribute('secondary-camera');

this all are specific  attribute which used from wc plugin, i dont know very much coding and dont know how to do this, thanks for your reply if could explain full code